# Automatic Date & Time

Tags: 20.04, date

Today something strange is happening. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with the latest updates, and the standard GNOME UI. My time suddenly started going wrong, and it seems to be due to the Automatic Date & Time setting in GNOME: when I disable it and enter the correct date manually (6 September 2020, 22:05 BST (London, United Kingdom)) everything works ok. But when I enable Automatic Date & Time, the clock goes to 6 September 2120, 20:30 GMT - around 100 years into the future!

Is there a known bug in the NTP servers or a problem with a recent OS update?

Comment: I'm having this problem as well in Ubuntu 20.04.  My computer says its 12:34am, but all other clocks say 12:19am. This is with auto time updates enabled.